# How to find the shortest paths of a weighted direct graph represented by an incidence matrix using Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

On the Internet, unfortunately, I only found Dijkstra’s algorithm for the adjacency matrix, but nowhere is there Dijkstra’s algorithm for the incidence matrix.

My incidence matrix (the first row of numbers are the numbers of vertices, what is in {} are edges, everything else is weight; for example, edge {1;3} with weight 5 is incident to vertex 3):

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

{0;1} 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

{0;2} 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0

{1;2} 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

{1;3} 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0

{1;4} 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0

{2;3} 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0

{2;4} 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

{2;5} 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0

{3;4} 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0

{3;5} 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0

{3;6} 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0

{4;5} 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0

{4;6} 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0

{5;6} 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0

{5;7} 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

{6;7} 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6

This graph:

[image]

In rectangles - the weight of the edge, and in circles just the numbers of the vertices, not the weight.

I'm trying to write an algorithm that, using Dijkstra's algorithm, will display the shortest paths from the vertex entered from the keyboard to all others, that is, the weight of the path and the path itself (the vertices through which this path passes) should be output.

I would be grateful if you help me write the algorithm =)

Just in case: I represent the matrix through a vector in the code:

```
vector<vector<int>> incidenceMatrix = {
  {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6},
};
```

Comment: *but nowhere is there Dijkstra’s algorithm for the incidence matrix* -- The internet has billions of pages.  You can't honestly say that the algorithm exists "nowhere".  And even if there doesn't exist one, wouldn't your goal be to simply create a function that converts an incidence matrix to an adjacency matrix, and then you have your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "orientated" you mean directed, I guess.  Each edge allows travel in one direction only.

> for example, edge {1;3} with weight 5 is incident to vertex 3

So you have an edge from 1 to 3 with weight 5.  So you can add that edge to just about any graph theory library, run the Dijkstra method and get your answer without any fuss.

For example using the PathFinder library ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder ) the input looks like this

```
format costs
l 0 1 1
l 0 2 2
l 1 2 1
l 1 3 5
l 1 4 2
l 2 3 2
l 2 4 1
l 2 5 4
s 0
e 4
```

and outputs

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, direct, exactly!) But, the thing is I have to work directly with matrix not using any wrotten library. For example, I have vector, which I wrote in description, and, for example, I have entered the value from keyborard for vertex from which we begin searching shortest paths, and I have to pass vector and that value as parameters to the method, which, using Dijkstra's algorithm, will show me all the shortest paths with the weighs to these paths.

Comment: So, take a look at any C++ implementation of Dijsktra and use that as I describe in my answer.  For example https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/a13ddd010554411767ec60b7550b32c95b64c038/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L15-L78

Comment: But methods from the library accept the adjacency matrix, don't they?

Comment: I don't have a problem, I help a lot when people put in effort. Not by doing their homework for them. @OP's question doesn't meet the SO requirements. I minimal reproducible example, with ONE question about a specific problem with that code. If we start to answer homework questions it will only invite others to do the same

Comment: they accept something like cGraph...

Comment: Libraries accept pairs of nodes and the weight for the link between them.  Internal storage might or might not be a adjacency matrix.